# sorting on the sql array in rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
@project_list =  Project.find_by_sql("select p.id, p.name, (select sum(i.estimated_hours) from issues i where  i.project_id = p.id)  as estimated_hours,(select sum(t.hours)  from time_entries t where p.id = t.project_id )  as Spent_Hours,(select u.firstname  from users u  where u.id IN(select user_id from members m where m.project_id = p.id and m.id IN   ( select member_id from member_roles   where role_id IN (select id from roles r where r.name  = 'Project Coordinator') )) limit 1 ) as Coordinator,(select u.firstname  from users u  where u.id IN(select user_id from members m where m.project_id = p.id and m.id IN   ( select member_id from member_roles   where role_id IN (select id from roles r where r.name  = 'Project Manager') )) limit 1) as  Manager   from projects p where p.status IN ('16','14','15','17','18','19','20')   group by p.id")
```

using above query I can get the records in my view page 
 Now i want further sorting or searching i.e. by coordinator,start date ,end date etc
 But I can not apply search method on the resulting array because find_by_sql returns an array.Though the above query seems difficult to write using the rails way So

1. is there any other way like make the read-only model  or some thing like that or
2. can any one helps me to write this query using rails way.

any help or suggestion would be a  great help

Comment: Well i need dynamic sorting so i have to use searching method like ransack or any text search method or meta search in rails, base on the selected value. On above query's result-record i need further dynamic sorting hope you clear with my question